# HTML Interpretted in Question Synopsis

Tags: bug, code-formatting

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788308/fill-file-input-after-form-submit-on-form-submit-error) I noticed that the HTML visible in the question synopsis was actually interpreted instead of being displayed as code.

[image]

Is that a bug or an unintended feature?

Comment: What is the difference between a bug and an unintended feature?

Comment: About $49.95 on the open market @Compass.

Comment: Possible possible? Possible.